# Iterate two Lists or Arrays with one ForEach statement in C#

Tags: c#

This just for general knowledge:

If I have two, let's say, **List**, and I want to iterate both with the same foreach loop, can we do that?

**Edit**

Just to clarify, I wanted to do this:

```
List<String> listA = new List<string> { "string", "string" };
List<String> listB = new List<string> { "string", "string" };

for(int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
    listB[i] = listA[i];
```

But with a foreach =)

Comment: The important word here is "zip".

Comment: Do you want to iterate two lists _in parallel_? Or do you want to iterate first one list, and then the other one (with a single statement)?

Comment: I think your way looks better than zip

Answer (score 347, accepted):

This is known as a [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) operation and has been supported since .NET 4.

With that, you would be able to write something like:

```
var numbers = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var words = new [] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (n, w) => new { Number = n, Word = w });
foreach(var nw in numbersAndWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nw.Number + nw.Word);
}
```

---

As an alternative to the anonymous type with the named fields, you can also save on braces by using a Tuple and its static `Tuple.Create` helper:

```
foreach (var nw in numbers.Zip(words, Tuple.Create)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(nw.Item1 + nw.Item2);
}
```

Comment: Here's an article on it: http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/11/03/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-3-intermezzo-linq-s-new-zip-operator.aspx

Comment: @Hugo: It's a standard construct in Functional Programming :)

Comment: Since C# 7, you could also use a ValueTuple (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45617748) instead of anonymous types or Tuple.Create.

I.e. `foreach ((var number, var word) in numbers.Zip(words, (n, w) => (n, w))) { ... }`.

Comment: Any performance gain other than simplicity? Zip will anyhow enumerate the lists.

Comment: Excellent work ! I used to think that the difference between for and foreach is that foreach is bound to list one list only but for can list multiple thanks to you for correcting me:)

Comment: I came here searching for guarantee of ordering, so it might be worth noting that the docs say. "The method merges each element of the first sequence with an element that has the same index in the second sequence."

Answer (score 22):

Since C# 7, you can use Tuples...

```
int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

foreach (var tuple in nums.Zip(words, (x, y) => (x, y)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{tuple.Item1}: {tuple.Item2}");
}

// or...
foreach (var tuple in nums.Zip(words, (x, y) => (Num: x, Word: y)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{tuple.Num}: {tuple.Word}");
}
```

**EDIT 2022-04-14**

The Zip extension method just got better since the original answer (and .NET Core 3.0), so you can now just write

```cs
int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

foreach (var (x, y) in nums.Zip(words))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x}: {y}");
}
```

and variant for three arrays is also supported since .NET 6

```cs
int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
string[] roman = { "I", "II", "III", "IV" };

foreach (var (x, y, z) in nums.Zip(words, roman))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x}: {y} ({z})");
}
```

Comment: What happens when the two lists are not the same length in this situation?

Comment: With `(x, y) => (x, y)` we can use named `tuple.x` and `tuple.y` which is elegant. So The second form could also be `(Num, Word) => (Num, Word)`

Comment: @JohnAugust It terminates after traversing the shorter sequence. From docs:" If the sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method merges sequences until it reaches the end of one of them. For example, if one sequence has three elements and the other one has four, the result sequence will have only three elements."

Answer (score 19):

If you don't want to wait for .NET 4.0, you could implement your own `Zip` method. The following works with .NET 2.0. You can adjust the implementation depending on how you want to handle the case where the two enumerations (or lists) have different lengths; this one continues to the end of the longer enumeration, returning the default values for missing items from the shorter enumeration.

```
static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, U>> Zip<T, U>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<U> second)
{
    IEnumerator<T> firstEnumerator = first.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<U> secondEnumerator = second.GetEnumerator();

    while (firstEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        if (secondEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<T, U>(firstEnumerator.Current, secondEnumerator.Current);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<T, U>(firstEnumerator.Current, default(U));
        }
    }
    while (secondEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return new KeyValuePair<T, U>(default(T), secondEnumerator.Current);
    }
}

static void Test()
{
    IList<string> names = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
    IList<int> ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> keyValuePair in ParallelEnumerate(names, ids))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Key ?? "<null>" + " - " + keyValuePair.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice method! :). You can make a few adjustments to use the same signature as .NET 4 Zip method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx and return resultSelector(first, second) instead of a KVP.

Comment: Note that this method does not dispose its enumerators which could become a problem, e.g. if it is used with enumerables over the lines of open files.

Answer (score 14):

You can use Union or Concat, the former removes duplicates, the later doesn't

```
foreach (var item in List1.Union(List1))
{
   //TODO: Real code goes here
}

foreach (var item in List1.Concat(List1))
{
   //TODO: Real code goes here
}
```

Comment: Another problem with using a Union is that it may throw away instances if they evaluate as being equal. That may not always be what you want.

Comment: I tough that his intention was to use collections with the same type,

Comment: @Mark Seemann, i already pointed that, he could also use Concat

Comment: Like Union, Concat only works if both lists are of the same type. Can't tell if this is what the OP needs or not, though...

Comment: This creates a new list that contains all elements.  This is a waste of memory.  Use the Linq Concat instead.

Comment: how do you know which item is from list1 and which item from list2 in a loop?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a custom IEnumerable<> extension method that can be used to loop through two lists simultaneously.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class LinqCombinedSort
    {
        public static void Test()
        {
            var a = new[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
            var b = new[] {3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4};

            var sorted = from ab in a.Combine(b)
                         orderby ab.Second
                         select ab.First;

            foreach(char c in sorted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Pair<TFirst, TSecond>> Combine<TFirst, TSecond>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> s1, IEnumerable<TSecond> s2)
        {
            using (var e1 = s1.GetEnumerator())
            using (var e2 = s2.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return new Pair<TFirst, TSecond>(e1.Current, e2.Current);
                }
            }

        }


    }
    public class Pair<TFirst, TSecond>
    {
        private readonly TFirst _first;
        private readonly TSecond _second;
        private int _hashCode;

        public Pair(TFirst first, TSecond second)
        {
            _first = first;
            _second = second;
        }

        public TFirst First
        {
            get
            {
                return _first;
            }
        }

        public TSecond Second
        {
            get
            {
                return _second;
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            if (_hashCode == 0)
            {
                _hashCode = (ReferenceEquals(_first, null) ? 213 : _first.GetHashCode())*37 +
                            (ReferenceEquals(_second, null) ? 213 : _second.GetHashCode());
            }
            return _hashCode;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as Pair<TFirst, TSecond>;
            if (other == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return Equals(_first, other._first) && Equals(_second, other._second);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I often need to execute an **action** on each pair in two collections. The Zip method is not useful in this case.

This extension method **ForPair** can be used:

```cs
public static void ForPair<TFirst, TSecond>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Action<TFirst, TSecond> action)
{
    using (var enumFirst = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var enumSecond = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumFirst.MoveNext() && enumSecond.MoveNext())
        {
            action(enumFirst.Current, enumSecond.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

So for example, you could write:

```cs
var people = new List<Person> { person1, person2 };
var wages = new List<decimal> { 10, 20 };

people.ForPair(wages, (p, w) => p.Wage = w);
```

Note however that this method cannot be used to modify the collection itself. This for example **will not work**:

```cs
List<String> listA = new List<string> { "string", "string" };
List<String> listB = new List<string> { "string", "string" };

listA.ForPair(listA, (c1, c2) => c1 = c2);  // Nothing will happen!
```

So in this case, the example in your own question is probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

No, you would have to use a for-loop for that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lst1.Count; i++)
{
    //lst1[i]...
    //lst2[i]...
}
```

You can't do something like

```
foreach (var objCurrent1 int lst1, var objCurrent2 in lst2)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: What if they have different counts?

Comment: Then a foreach which would accept an arbitrary list of enumerables wouldn't work as well, thus rendering the whole thing useless.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one element with the corresponding one you could do

```
Enumerable.Range(0, List1.Count).All(x => List1[x] == List2[x]);
```

That will return true if every item is equal to the corresponding one on the second list

If that's almost but not quite what you want it would help if you elaborated more.

Answer (score 0):

This method would work for a list implementation and could be implemented as an extension method.

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    var first = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    var second = new List<string> {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};

    foreach(var value in this.Zip(first, second, (x, y) => new {Number = x, Text = y}))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",value.Number, value.Text);
    }
}

public IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(List<TFirst> first, List<TSecond> second, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> selector)
{
    if (first.Count != second.Count)
        throw new Exception();  

    for(var i = 0; i < first.Count; i++)
    {
        yield return selector.Invoke(first[i], second[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply use a local integer variable if the lists have the same length:

```
List<classA> listA = fillListA();
List<classB> listB = fillListB();

var i = 0;
foreach(var itemA in listA)
{
    Console.WriteLine(itemA  + listB[i++]);
}
```

Comment: If you have to index one of the lists, the advantage of `foreach` is lost. And in this case, your constraint is actually that `listB` must be **at least** as long as `listA`, which seems like an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score -3):

I understand/hope that the lists have the same length:
No, your only bet is going with a plain old standard for loop.