# Tuples and unpacking assignment support in C#?

Tags: c#, tuples, iterable-unpacking, decomposition

In Python I can write

```
def myMethod():
    #some work to find the row and col
    return (row, col)

row, col = myMethod()
mylist[row][col] # do work on this element
```

But in C# I find myself writing out

```
int[] MyMethod()
{
    // some work to find row and col
    return new int[] { row, col }
}

int[] coords = MyMethod();
mylist[coords[0]][coords[1]] //do work on this element
```

The Pythonic way is obivously much cleaner. Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: I'd probably use out parameters for that..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: The Framework Design Guidelines recommend against out parameters if they can be avoided.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I thought about out parameters, but they make me feel dirty for some reason

Comment: Hmm, never heard any argument against them.  `TryXXX()` methods seem to use them all the time..

Comment: @MikeChristensen And every-time I use then I want to stab someone [with a rubber knife] for not having the concept of Option/Maybe core in .NET :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a set of [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) classes in .NET:

```
Tuple<int, int> MyMethod()
{
    // some work to find row and col
    return Tuple.Create(row, col);
}
```

But there's no compact syntax for unpacking them like in Python:

```
Tuple<int, int> coords = MyMethod();
mylist[coords.Item1][coords.Item2] //do work on this element
```

Comment: Note for causal reader: `Tuple<...>` is standard in .NET4+ only.

Comment: Note for other readers, a 2-tuple can be created in .NET < 4 (in essence) by using a KeyValuePair instead.

Answer (score 60):

For .NET 4.7 and later, you can pack and unpack a `ValueTuple`:

```
(int, int) MyMethod()
{
    return (row, col);
}

(int row, int col) = MyMethod();
// mylist[row][col]
```

For .NET 4.6.2 and earlier, you should install [System.ValueTuple](https://packages.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple):

```
PM> Install-Package System.ValueTuple
```

Comment: note that you can use `var` in this expression. (not sure which version this is possible from)

Answer (score 7):

An extension might get it closer to Python tuple unpacking, not more efficient but more readable (and Pythonic):

```
public class Extensions
{
  public static void UnpackTo<T1, T2>(this Tuple<T1, T2> t, out T1 v1, out T2 v2)
  {
    v1 = t.Item1;
    v2 = t.Item2;
  }
}

Tuple<int, int> MyMethod() 
{
   // some work to find row and col
   return Tuple.Create(row, col);
}

int row, col;    
MyMethod().UnpackTo(out row, out col);
mylist[row][col]; // do work on this element
```

Answer (score 2):

C# is a strongly-typed language with a type system that enforces a rule that functions can have either none (`void`) or 1 return value.  C# 4.0 introduces the Tuple class:

```
Tuple<int, int> MyMethod()
{
    return Tuple.Create(0, 1);
}

// Usage:
var myTuple = MyMethod();
var row = myTuple.Item1;  // value of 0
var col = myTuple.Item2;  // value of 1
```

Comment: A strongly typed language is not restricted to returning a single value. Scheme is one example. Strong typing != static typing; Python and Scheme are strongly-but-dynamically typed.

Comment: This is true, it should probably be worded that C#'s type system restricts return values of functions to a single type.

Comment: additionally, Go is strongly and statically typed but supports multiple return values

Answer (score 2):

Here is a zip example with value unpacking. Here zip returns an iterator over tuples.

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};
string[] words = {"one", "two", "three"};

foreach ((var n, var w) in numbers.Zip(words, Tuple.Create))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", n, w);
}
```

Output:

```
1 -> one
2 -> two
3 -> three
```