# using foreach loop for two lists in c# for geting lists values

Tags: c#, list, loops, foreach

```
List<String> listA = new List<string> { "A1", "A2" };
List<String> listB = new List<string> { "B1", "B2" };

for(int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
{
    text += listA[i] + " and " + listB[i];
}
```

How can I do this using a `foreach` loop ?

Comment: why would you want that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955766/iterate-two-lists-or-arrays-with-one-foreach-statment-in-c-sharp

Comment: you can't do it in a simple and efficient way. the for loop looks fine but use a stringbuilder

Answer (score 14):

You can use Linq and the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method:

```
List<String> listA = new List<string> { "A1", "A2" };
List<String> listB = new List<string> { "B1", "B2" };

foreach (var pair in listA.Zip(listB, (a,b) => new {A = a, B = b}))
{
    text += pair.A + " and " + pair.B;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would happen if listB is shorter than listA ?

Comment: @Alex I believe it stops iterating on the shortest enumerable. The linked documentation above confirms this in the remarks.

Comment: @Alex from msdn: "If the input sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method combines elements until it reaches the end of one of the sequences. For example, if one sequence has three elements and the other one has four, the result sequence has only three elements."

Comment: I'd +2 this one if I could ... shame on me for not researching the lanuage properly, I wasn't aware of this extension

Comment: i try that but listA.Zip is not in c#. zip erroe

Comment: @HinaHanif Zip is an extension method introduced in .net 3.5 you need to using it's namspace: so add this line to your source file: `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this with a `foreach` any better than you are already doing it with `for` -- `foreach` is really only designed to work well when there is only one sequence to enumerate.

However, you can do it very conveniently with LINQ:

```
text = string.Join("", listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => a + " and " + b));
```

This requires .NET 4 both for [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) and for the [specific overload of `string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876).

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this is doing that with  simple Enumerator:

```
IEnumerator<string>  enumerator = listB.GetEnumerator(); 
enumerator.MoveNext();
foreach(var stra in listA) {
    text += stra + " and " + enumerator.Current.ToString() + ", ";
    enumerator.MoveNext();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ

```
string text = listA.Zip(listB, (a, b) => new {A = a, B = b}).Aggregate("", (current, pair) => current + (pair.A + " and " + pair.B));
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you do not want to use LINQ and you want them to iterate parallel you have few options - with new classes etc. like below OR you can use **foreach**, but only for one of the lists, like this:

```
List<String> listA = new List<string> { "A1", "A2" };
List<String> listB = new List<string> { "B1", "B2" };
string text = "";
int i = 0;
foreach (string s in listA) {
   text += s + " and " + listB [i++] + "\n";
}
Console.WriteLine (text);
```

or make it a bit nicer using GetEnumerator:

```
List<String> listA = new List<string> { "A1", "A2" };
List<String> listB = new List<string> { "B1", "B2" };
string text = "";       
List<string>.Enumerator e = listB.GetEnumerator ();
foreach (string s in listA) {
   e.MoveNext ();
   text += s + " and " + e.Current + "\n";
}
Console.WriteLine (text);
```

also you can create yourself an Enumberable metacollection which will return out of that always a simple string array - for that you will need to create an Enumerator and a class which is derieves from IEnumerable:

First the Enumerator:

```
private class DoubleStringEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    private DoubleString _elemList;
    private int _index;
    public DoubleStringEnumerator(DoubleString doubleStringObjt)
    {
        _elemList = doubleStringObjt;
        _index = -1;
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        _index = -1;
    }
    public object Current {
        get {
            return _elemList.getNext();
        }
    }
    public bool MoveNext ()
    {
        _index++;
        if (_index >= _elemList.Length)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

The **Current** method does not really reflects it's name in the given example - but it is for learning purposes.

Now the class:

```
public class DoubleString : IEnumerable
{
    public int Length;
    List<String> listA;
    List<String> listB;
    List<string>.Enumerator eA,eB;
    public DoubleString(List<String> newA,List<String> newB)
    {
        if(newA.Count != newB.Count) {
            throw new Exception("Lists lengths must be the same");    
        }
        listA = newA;
        listB = newB;
        eA = listA.GetEnumerator ();
        eB = listB.GetEnumerator ();
        Length = listA.Count;
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator ()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)new DoubleStringEnumerator(this);
    }
    public string[] getNext ()
    {
        eA.MoveNext ();
        eB.MoveNext ();
        return new string[] {eA.Current ,eB.Current };
    }
}
```

And the code itself:

```
List<String> listA = new List<string> { "A1", "A2" };
List<String> listB = new List<string> { "B1", "B2" };               
DoubleString newDoubleString = new DoubleString (listA, listB);             
string text = "";
foreach (string[] s in newDoubleString) {
    text += s[0] + " and " + s[1] + "\n";
}
Console.WriteLine (text);
```

Of course still better to use LINQ. The code is not optimsied, but I had no compiler with me so writting from my head - hope it will clarify few things. Feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score -2):

```
List<int> = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<String> words = new [] { "one", "two", "three" };

var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (n, w) => new { Number = n, Word = w });
foreach(var nw in numbersAndWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nw.Number + nw.Word);
}
```

Comment: This is simply a rehash of the [duplicate question mentioned in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1955780/358221).

Answer (score -3):

**Here is the solution using foreach:**

```
string text = null;
int cnt = 0;

List<String> listA = new List<string> { "A1", "A2" };
List<String> listB = new List<string> { "B1", "B2" };

foreach (string i in listA)
  {
         text += listA[cnt] + " and " + listB[cnt];
         cnt++;
  }
```

**Thanks & Regards,

Subhankar**

Comment: why are you using listA[cnt] instead of i?

Comment: @Francesco don't you see that the i is a string variable and we can't access an array index using string.

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli can we access an array index using string?

Comment: yes, it's a string, and listA[cnt] is ...? I mean, why are you wasting time accessing an array to get what you already have?

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli but if i won't fetch it index wise in foreach block so how can i concatenate both the string like A1 and B1, A2 and B2..

Comment: `text += i + " and " + listB[cnt];`