# How to iterate though and change background color of each item in a list

Tags: c#

I'm trying loop through and change the `Console.BackgroundColor` for each item in a list, and am wondering how I would go about doing so.

```
public static List<int> myList = new List<int>();

foreach(//loop through the list){
  Console.BackgroundColor = //set background color for each item in myList
}
```

Comment: Why not use an index or Dictionary?

Comment: How woudl I go about doing that?

Comment: The documentation on Console.BackgroundColor actually has an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.backgroundcolor?view=net-6.0#examples) on how to loop trough all the available colors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using foreach loop for two lists in c# for geting lists values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410593/using-foreach-loop-for-two-lists-in-c-sharp-for-geting-lists-values)

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to try rephrase. I want to print out each item in cardTypeStore with each color from cardColorStore. Would you mind showing an example?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine That should work for looping through two lists, I just don't know how to change the color for each one.

Comment: Why not use a for loop?  It is better suited for this task.  Otherwise you create an index and increase it at the end of the foreach loop.

Comment: Could you/someone give some sort of demo on how to do this? I'm pretty new to programming.

Comment: @ConsoleCreative Have you checked basic C# tutorials / books / courses? I'm sorry if this sounds kinda rude unintentionally, but given your comments on this and the answer you miss some knowledge fuel to get up to speed to go anywhere.

Comment: I'll make sure to learn more about how the language works, and also OOP. Thanks 

Comment: Best not to use this site in place of a basic language tutorial

Comment: This edit does not fix the question, because it invalidates the answer that was given, and because it is needlessly simplified ("how do I iterate" is so trivial that nobody ever saw fit to make a canonical for it, even though everyone needs to know). The original question should not have been closed as "needs more focus", because it is perfectly understandable, and a common problem with a canonical. Instead, it should have been closed as a duplicate of that canonical: [Iterate two Lists or Arrays with one ForEach statement in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955766/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a foreach loop, you can use a for loop.  The benefit of using the for loop is the index, which can be used to access both collections.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cardTypeStore.Count; i++)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = cardColorStore[i];
    Console.Write(cardTypeStore[i]);
}
```

This will require both collections to have the same number of items, otherwise you risk an Index Out of Range Exception.

A better option, if possible, is to use a class to hold your data.  If you want to make changes later, this is much easier to maintain.

```
public class CardData
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Color { get; set; }
}
```

Then you create a single list that you can iterate over using for or foreach.

```
var cardDataList = new List<CardData>();

// ... populate list with data

foreach (var cardData in cardDataList)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = cardData.Color;
    Console.Write(cardData.Type);
}
```

Comment: One thing, I want to store the `var cardDataList = new List<CardData>();` as a global variable, but it's giving me the error `The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration.` Would you know why by any chance?

Comment: For class level variable you cannot use the `var` keyword.  Instead use the type.  `List<CardData> cardDataList = new List<CardData>();`

Comment: That fixed it great! One other question (sorry for so many) I'm adding data to the old lists by going `cardTypeStore.add(//random int here)` and `cardColorStore.add(//random type here)`, but it's throwing `Argument 'number' cannot convert from TypeA to TypeB`. Any clue why?