# How to use two variables in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I am using dotConnect linq to sqlite. What i want to do is use two variable in a foreach loop. Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955766/iterate-two-lists-or-arrays-with-one-foreach-statment-in-c-sharp) code but it is not working. This is my code snippet.

```
    bool check_units(int id)
    {
        MainDataContext medic = new MainDataContext();
        bool check = false;
        var medic_query = from m in medic.Medicines
                          orderby m.Id
                          where m.Id == id
                          select m;

        var invo_query = from inv in medic.Invoices
                         orderby inv.Id
                         where inv.Id == id
                         select inv;

        var med_inv = medic_query.Zip(invo_query, (m, i) => new { Medicine = m, Invoice = i });

        foreach(var mi in med_inv)
        {
            if (mi.Medicine.UNIT > mi.Invoice.UNIT)
            {
                mi.Medicine.UNIT -= mi.Invoice.UNIT;
                if (mi.Medicine.UNIT < 10)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(mi.Medicine.Name + " is short in Invertory!\nUnits Remaining: " + mi.Medicine.UNIT,
                        "Inventory Empty", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
                chk = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Enough Stock!\nUnits Remaining: " + mi.Medicine.UNIT,
                    "Inventory Short", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        medic.SubmitChanges();
        return chk;
    }
```

The Problem that i am facing is my code gives an error

> The query operator 'Zip' is not supported.

There is no kind of syntax error or warning.
I think that Zip operator can not be used with linqtosql type of queries!

Waiting for support!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the underlying query provider cannot translate the `Zip` method to raw SQL.  Since you're not applying any additional filters the simplest method is to hydrate the query using `AsEnumerable`:

```
    var med_inv = medic_query.AsEnumerable()
                             .Zip(invo_query, (m, i) => new { Medicine = m, Invoice = i });
```

Are you certain that the records from each query line up properly?  This looks like it should be a `Join` but since you don't specify if/how the records are related we can't tell what the proper join would be.

Comment: Thanks Did what you suggested but now the control is not entering the foreach loop!

Comment: Actually both the tables are same!
Difference is Table Medicine is the Inventory and the other one is for invoice record!
This snippet was my Bad Logic, now i will modify my code that would require only one query :p

Comment: Though i am going to change my code, still i might need this in future. Why is this code not working or all the other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you see has to do with `Zip` method not being supported by the `IQueryable<T>` provider. Forcing the move of your data to memory should fix this problem - you can use `AsEnumerable` to do the cast, or bring the data in memory explicitly, like this:

```
var medList = medic_query.ToList();
var invoList = invo_query.ToList();
var med_inv = medList.Zip(invoList, (m, i) => new { Medicine = m, Invoice = i });
```

This shouldn't have much impact on the performance, because `Zip` is going to bring both lists into memory anyway.

Comment: The key here is that you pull the two querys down individually, so you do 2 DB round trips, rather than merging them into one query (in theory, one could imagine a `Zip` implementation that put both into a single batch).  I'm not sure if there is any other way of batching the query queries using that query provider.

Comment: @Servy I agree - if the query provider cannot do it, you need to run `Zip` in memory.

Comment: Thanks Did what you suggested but now the control is not entering the foreach loop!
Same as the other suggestion :(

Comment: @MuneebMirza Check `medList.Count` then: it is zero.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Thanks Sir! You helped me alot. now i got what mistake i had made!

Answer (score 2):

Add AsEnumerable() calls:

```
var med_inv = medic_query.AsEnumerable().Zip(invo_query.AsEnumerable(), (m, i) => new { Medicine = m, Invoice = i });
```

Comment: Thanks Did what you suggested but now the control is not entering the foreach loop! Same as the other suggestion :(

Comment: That's because your `medic_query` and `invo_query` don't return any items from database.

Comment: Thanks Sir! You helped me alot. now i got what mistake i had made!