# Jump out from Inner-Foreach to Outer-Foreach, Keep Inner-Foreach where you left it

Tags: c#, foreach

I have the following code:

```
foreach (XNode rowXml in elements.Nodes())
                         {        
                             foreach (DataRow rowDB in dataSetDB.Tables[0].Rows)
                             {
                                 string itemDB = rowDB[0].ToString().ToUpper();
                                 string itemXml = rowXml.ToString().ToUpper();
                                 if (itemDB == itemXml)
                                 {    
                                    //If itemDB == itemXml; jump to Outer_Foreach
                                 }
                                 if (itemDB != itemXml)
                                 {  
                                     //If itemDB != itemXml; jump to Outer_Foreach
                                 }
                             }
```

How is it possible to get out of Inner-Foreach and up to Outer-Foreach, and still keep both foreach where you left it. I am looping through a DB and XML table rows. Break; completley jumps out of the Inner-Foreach and im not able to catch where I left it, so I start back on index[0], when I loop through it over and over again.

Comment: Strange `if` condition, you jump to the outer-foreach `if(itemDB == itemXml)` and also `if (itemDB != itemXml)`. Do you notice something? So basically you are doing nothing.

Comment: Well, I have code inside those if's

Comment: You should at least use `else if(itemDB != itemXml)` or even better `else` since both conditions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Can you explain what in general are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have two Tables. One in DB and one in XML file. 
I check the PK in the first DB row with the PK in the first row of the XML table. If they are similar or different ill do stuff. I then check the second row PK of DB with the second row PK of the XML file. And then it goes on with the rest of the rows.

Comment: A long shot, but your code looks something like you want the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955766/iterate-two-lists-or-arrays-with-one-foreach-statement-in-c-sharp  ---- edit, you just wrote exactly what I thought. You want the ZIP operation. See the linked stackoverflow question/answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need 'for' loop.

```
 int i = 0;
 int k = 0;
 bool shouldBreak;

 var nodes = elements.Nodes();
 var rows = dataSetDB.Tables[0].Rows;

 for (i = 0; i < nodes.Count(); i++)
 {
     for(k = 0; k < rows.Count(); k++)
     {
        string itemDB = rows[k][0].ToString().ToUpper();
        string itemXml = nodes[i].ToString().ToUpper();
            if (itemDB == itemXml)
            {   
                shouldBreak = true;
                break;
            }
            if (itemDB != itemXml)
            {  
                shouldBreak = true;
                break;
            }
     }
     if (toBreak)
         break;
 }
```

Now if you'll break the inner loop can know where it broke by accessing i and k

Comment: How would it be possible to use a 'for' loop , to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is [stolen from this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955780/574115). What you want to achieve is a zip operation. For more information see the answer that I linked.

```
var xmlNodes = elements.Nodes();
var dbNodes = dataSetDB.Tables[0].Rows;

var xmlAndDB = xmlNodes.Zip(dbNodes , (x, d) => new { xNode = x, dNode = d });

foreach(var xd in xmlAndDB )
{
    Console.WriteLine(xd.xNode + xd.dNode);

    string itemDB = xd.dNode[0].ToString().ToUpper();
    string itemXml = xd.xNode.ToString().ToUpper();

    if (itemDB == itemXml)
    {    
        //If itemDB == itemXml;
    }
    else /* if (itemDB != itemXml) */ 
    {  
        //If itemDB != itemXml;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get following error mate, "The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip<TFirst,TSecond,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.I‌​Enumerable<TFirst>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSecond>, System.Func<TFirst,TSecond,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."