# How to iterate for larger list using foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

I have two list ,list1 of size 5 elements and list2 of size 6 elements.
I want to iterate for larger list size(eg. 6 in this case) using foreach statement but the problem is I am not using if condition to check which list is larger .
So how can I do the necessary task.

```
if (list1.Count>list2.Count) // here I donot want to use if statement
{                            // do it in 1 statement only
    Size=list1.Count;
    foreach (var item in list1)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
else 
{
    Size = list2.Count;
    foreach (var item in list2)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: What is issue with `if-condition`?

Comment: First of all there are many lists in my requirement and it is looking complicated too

Comment: If a simple comparison in an `if` statement looks complicated to you, I'm not sure programming is for you.

Comment: @Rik how will i use 'if' statement if there are 5 different list and will do the same task ,Thank you:p

Comment: @user1909259 you want to know which list size is greater out of many lists. And then you want to run foreach on the larger one only?

Comment: @user1909259 Aha, now we're getting to the root of the problem. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move the condition into the foreach:

```
foreach(var item in (list1.Count > list2.Count ? list1 : list2))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

If you have several Lists (more than 2), you can create collection and get the maximum using LINQ:

```
var myLists = new List<List<T>>(); // T is the generic type of your Lists, obviously
myLists.Add(list1);
myLists.Add(list2);
...
myLists.Add(listN);

// iterate over the largest one:
foreach (var item in myLists.First(l => l.Count == lists.Max(x=>x.Count)))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I either donot want to use '> ? :' too.

Comment: @user1909259 Then use `<` and swap the List :p

Comment: Why not? How else do you propose to select the bigger of the lists without comparing their sizes?

Comment: I was thinking any inbuilt standard method

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I should have thought of this solution. :p

Comment: The `Zip` operation in that link does something completely different from what you described.

Comment: I am working on that, somewhat it has solved the problem by creating a new list variable by merging other two.

Comment: By the way what is 'lists' in foreach statement

Answer (score 4):

```
var list = list1.Count > list2.Count ? list1 : list2;

foreach(var item in  list)
```

Comment: Even though Rik's answer would also work, I like this solution better since it's more readable

Comment: I agree this is more readable then my answer, but OP specified "do it in 1 statement only". In your case, I would suggest renaming `list` to "largerList` or something for even more clarity.

Comment: Thank you guys I have found the solution on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955766/iterate-two-lists-or-arrays-with-one-foreach-statement-in-c-sharp), sorry to bother you.:p