# Iterate two Arrays with ForEach statement in C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 array

```
string[] Namesvalues = Names.Split(',');
string[] TotalValues = Total.Split(',');
```

Above both arrays have exactly equal values.what i want to do is to iterate above two arrays in parallel and want to get one by one value from both arrays.

Can any one tell me how can i do that??

Comment: "both arrays have exactly equal values", I assume you are saying they have the same number of elements?

Comment: @Dirk yeah right both have the same number of elements

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a normal for loop and use the iterator to access the arrays. After checking the lengths are the same. Assuming you want to compare of use them.

Comment: You can use typical for loop instead of foreach... any reason you are looking for foreach solution or you just want to iterate?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955766/iterate-two-lists-or-arrays-with-one-foreach-statement-in-c-sharp?rq=1) provides answer to your exact question. Note that it may be better to create custom class (Name,Total) instead of 2 separate arrays or simply use `for` loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply use a `for`-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NamesValues.Length; i++)
{
    string name = NamesValues[i];
    string totalValue = TotalValues[i];
}
```

If the length is different you could use [`ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb494386%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
for(int i = 0; i < Math.Max(NamesValues.Length, TotalValues.Length) ; i++)
{
    string name = NamesValues.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
    string totalValue = TotalValues.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
}
```

---

You also could use  [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to create an anonymous type with both values:

```
var namesAndValues = NamesValues.Zip(TotalValues, 
    (n, tv) => new { Name = n, TotalValue = tv });
foreach(var nv in namesAndValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} Value: {1}", nv.Name + nv.TotalValue);
}
```

Note that the second approach using a `for-loop` and `ElementAtOrDefault` is different to to the `Enumerable.Zip` approach.

- The former iterates  **both arrays completely**  and `ElementAtOrDefault` returns `null` for the value of the smaller array if there is no element at that index.
- The latter `Zip`  combines elements only until it reaches the **end of one of the sequences**.

So when you use `Math.Min` instead of `Math.Max` in the `for`-loop you get a similar behaviour, but then you should use the first approach anyway since there's no need for `ElementAtOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//exactly equal length
for (int i = 0; i < Namesvalues.Length; i++)
{
    var name = Namesvalues[i];
    var total = TotalValues[i];
}
```