# Autofixture generate collection without duplicates (by ID)

Tags: c#, .net, testing, autofixture

I have following classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<DescriptionInfo> Descriptions { get; set; }
}


public class DescriptionInfo
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create Foo instance, using Autofixture. However, the LanguageId must come from a predefined list. Therefore I've created following customization:

```
public class LanguageIdSpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private static readonly List<int> LanguageIds = new List<int> {
        1,
        2,
        666,
    };

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var info = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (info != null)
        {
            if (info.Name == "LanguageID")
            {
                return LanguageIds.GetRandomElement();
            }
        }
        return new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}
```

Now everything is good:

```
Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customizations.Add(new LanguageIdSpecimenBuilder());
var foo = fixture.Create<Foo>();
```

However, there is one more requirement: there must be no duplicated entries for one language ID. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**
For example, valid instances are:

```
Foo1:
 - LanguageId: 1, Value: "english description_ae154c"
 - LanguageId: 2, Value: "zuzulu_510b7g"

Foo2:
 - LanguageId: 1, Value: "english description_87f5de"
 - LanguageId: 666, Value: "chinese_35e450"
 - LanguageId: 2, Value: "zuzulu_fe830d"
```

Invalid instance:

```
Foo1:
 - LanguageId: 1, Value: "_04dcd6"
 - LanguageId: 1, Value: "_66ccc4"
 - LanguageId: 2, Value: "zuzulu_c05b0f"
```

Comment: The list of valid language IDs contains three values. What should happen if you create four `Foo` instances?

Comment: I've added examples. The requirement is for particular Foo instances, not global-wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - let me suggest your POCes can be more precise. If you don't allow descriptions with same `LanguageID` in the list, you can remodel your POCes like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public ISet<DescriptionInfo> Descriptions { get; set; }
}

public class DescriptionInfo
{
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var anotherInfo = (DescriptionInfo)obj;
        return anotherInfo.LanguageID == LanguageID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return LanguageID;
    }
}
```

And the problem is gone:

```
fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(typeof(ISet<DescriptionInfo>),
  typeof(HashSet<DescriptionInfo>)));
fixture.Customizations.Add(new LanguageIdSpecimenBuilder());
var foo = fixture.Create<Foo>();
```

If you can't/ don't want to remodel your POCes, you should focus in the custom builder on the property you want to set right - `Descriptions`.

```
public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
{
    var info = request as PropertyInfo;
    if (info != null && info.Name == "Descriptions" && info.DeclaringType == typeof(Foo))
    {
        if (info.Name == "Descriptions")
        {
            return context.Create<List<DescriptionInfo>>()
             .GroupBy(g => g.LanguageId)
             .Select(g => g.First())
             .ToList();
         }
    }
    if (info != null && info.Name == "LanguageId" && info.DeclaringType == typeof(DescriptionInfo))
    {
        return LanguageIds.GetRandomElement();
    }
    return new NoSpecimen(request);
}
```

Final note - you're code snippet is wrong - string comparison is case sensitive; so it should be `info.Name == "LanguageId"`, also it is great idea to check the type that declares the property - not just the property name.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Indeed there is a case error & checking declaring type is a very good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the ID values to be unique on a single `Foo` instance, you'll probably be best off customizing the `Foo` type itself.

You'll probably want to let AutoFixture deal with the other parts of `Foo`, except the `DescriptionInfo` values. One way to do this is to create an `ISpecimenCommand`, which can be used as a post-processor of generated values:

```
public class UniqueIDsOnFooCommand : ISpecimenCommand
{
    private static readonly int[] languageIds = new [] { 1, 2, 666, };
    private static readonly Random random = new Random();

    public void Execute(object specimen, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var foo = specimen as Foo;
        if (foo == null)
            return;

        foreach (var t in
            foo.Descriptions.Zip(Shuffle(languageIds), Tuple.Create))
        {
            var description = t.Item1;
            var id = t.Item2;
            description.LanguageId = id;
        }            
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(IReadOnlyCollection<T> source)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(_ => random.Next());
    }
}
```

This implementation uses a ready-made array of well-known language IDs, [shuffles them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2019433/126014), and then [zips them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955780/126014) with the descriptions.

You can package this command in a Customization that changes the behaviour of the `Foo` type:

```
public class FooCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Add(
            SpecimenBuilderNodeFactory.CreateTypedNode(
                typeof(Foo),
                new Postprocessor(
                    new MethodInvoker(
                        new ModestConstructorQuery()),
                    new CompositeSpecimenCommand(
                        new AutoPropertiesCommand(),
                        new UniqueIDsOnFooCommand()))));
    }
}
```

The following test passes:

```
[Fact]
public void CreateFoos()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new FooCustomization());
    fixture.Behaviors.Add(new TracingBehavior());

    var foos = fixture.CreateMany<Foo>();

    Assert.True(
        foos.All(f => f
            .Descriptions
            .Select(x => x.LanguageId)
            .Distinct()
            .Count() == f.Descriptions.Count),
        "Languaged IDs should be unique for each foo.");
}
```

The created `Foo` values look like this:

```
  Foo:
  - LanguageId: 1, Value: "Valueefd1268c-56e9-491a-a43d-3f385ea0dfd8"
  - LanguageId: 666, Value: "Value461d7130-7bc0-4e71-96a8-432c019567c9"
  - LanguageId: 2, Value: "Valuee2604a80-f113-485c-8276-f19a97bca505"

  Foo:
  - LanguageId: 2, Value: "Value66eee598-1895-4c0d-b3c6-4262711fe394"
  - LanguageId: 666, Value: "Valuef9a58482-13c6-4491-a690-27b243af6404"
  - LanguageId: 1, Value: "Valueeb133071-dad7-4bff-b8ef-61d3505f1641"

  Foo:
  - LanguageId: 1, Value: "Valuea1161dc6-75e5-45a3-9333-f6bca01e882b"
  - LanguageId: 666, Value: "Value31332272-5b61-4d51-8572-172b781e5f6b"
  - LanguageId: 2, Value: "Value83f80569-277d-49b2-86e5-be256075835e"
```

All that said, [consider a different design that doesn't involve settable collection properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389).

Comment: Also a nice solution, even it seems to me that this is a little less "hacky" than @ondrej-svejdar answer. However because he was first, I'll keep his answer as accepted.

Comment: @piotrwest No worries. The important part is that you got a useful answer to your question.