# Nesting loop to get one of each

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a look to print each of every value once:

Something like this.

Lets pretend that the object `letters` contains "one,two ...ten"

And then there is the object `numbers` that contains "1,2,3,4...10"

Now if I want the loop to print:

```
One 
1 
Two
2 
Three
3
```

How would the loop look like?

I tried it like this:

```
     foreach (var i in letters)
{
       Console.WriteLine(i);

     foreach(var a in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
}
```

But this returns:

```
One 
1
2
Two
1
2
Three
1
2
```

And that result isn't what I want..

How can I nest the loops to make it print the way  I want it?

Comment: can you show the object letters / numbers

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955766/iterate-two-lists-or-arrays-with-one-foreach-statement-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Simon.S This has been open for a long while. If one of these answers solved your issue, please  accept it to make it more visible for those looking for a similar answer.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can use `IEnumerable<T>.Zip(...)`, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx), to make combinations.

```
var data = letters.Zip(numbers, (l, n) => new { letter = l, number = n})
foreach (var item in data) {
    Console.Writeline(item.letter);
    Console.Writeline(item.number);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use forloop insted of foreach use it like this

```
for (int i=0;i<letters.length;i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(letters[i]);
  Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Nested loops aren't necessary in this case.

Comment: in case `letters.Count` == `numbers.Count` - otherwise `i < Math.Min(letters.Count,numbers.Count )`

Answer (score 3):

Don't do two nested loops, they are for enumerating over all possible pairs from two collections.

Instead, make a loop on the index, and use it for both collections, or use LINQ's `Zip` method:

```
foreach (var pair in letters.Zip(numbers, (l, n) => new {Letter=l, Number=n})) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pair.Letter, pair.Number);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Numbers and Letters are collections that derive from IEnumerable, you could do something like this:

```
 var zipped = letters.Zip(numbers, Tuple.Create);

 foreach (var tuple in zipped)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1);
     Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item2);
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible to loop more than two values using this method?

Comment: Yeah it is possible. If all of your collections are the same length, you zip the first pair, then zip the results of the next pair, but it would be a bit untidy as you would end up with nested tuples @Simon.S

Answer (score 1):

You need a single loop to iterate over both lists:

```
for (int index = 0; index < letters.Count; index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(letters[index]);
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[index]);
}
```

This presupposes that your lists are the same length. If they're not you'd have to set the upper limit to the length of the shorter list.

```
for (int index = 0; index < Math.Min(letters.Count, numbers.Count); index++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close - the second loop should not be within the first, but you should use one loop to iterate over both arrays. Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < letters.size(); i++) {
 Console.WriteLine(letters.getItem(i));
 Console.WriteLine(numbers.getItem(i));
}
```

Note that this assumes a size() method to return the number of items and a getItem() method to return a specific item from the object.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that for every time your outside loop runs, the inside one runs twice.

That's because your loops are nested, there's no getting around this.
If you **absolutely must** use nested loops for this, you'd have to add a check whether your number has been printed yet

Something like:

```
foreach(var i in letters)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);

    foreach(var a in numbers)
    {
        if (a.isPrinted) //if it has been printed already
        {
            continue; //skip ahead
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.number);
            a.isPrinted = true;
            break; //stop and jump out of the foreach loop
        }
    }
}
```

This also means that each number is actually an object that holds the `bool isPrinted` and `int number`
I wouldn't doing it like that, it's ridiculously inefficient.
You should do what others have already suggested.